Does sulfuric acid in snow damage fabric?
Had to do an emergency work in deep snow, in results my black cotton clothes were soaked in it. To my basic knowledge “regular” snow may contain not only salts but also sulfuric acid.
Will snow-covered clothes contaminate a washer and dryer with sulfuric acid, causing all next loads to be faded or degraded..?  If so, what can be done after the fact.
According to channels, there was 1 or <1ppb of sulfur dioxide in the air at that time. Chart from 2023 for sulfur + nitrogen wet deposition shows 324-402 eq/ha, hydrogen about 5.4 pH in approximated area.
Air pollution data for Northeast US:
Area:
https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/monitoring/reference-maps/us-climate-regions
Annual acid rain data (up to 2023):
https://nadp.slh.wisc.edu/maps-data/ntn-gradient-maps/
Hydrogen ion concentration data (between 5.7-5.3-5.4):
https://nadp.slh.wisc.edu/filelib/maps/NTN/pdfs/2023/pH_2023.pdf
Sulfur + Nitrogen wet deposition data (between 402-324-537)
https://nadp.slh.wisc.edu/filelib/maps/NTN/pdfs/2023/SplusN_dep_2023.pdf
Sulfur dioxide (last year data):
https://gaftp.epa.gov/castnet/tdep/CURRENT_images/so2_dw-20212023.png
PA Department of Environmental Protection - current Air Quality Index Report (my area had the SO2_01 (1) and SO2_24 (2) fields left blank):
https://www.dep.pa.gov/Business/Air/BAQ/MonitoringTopics/AirQualityIndex/pages/default.aspx
https://www.dep.state.pa.us/dep/deputate/airwaste/aq/aqm/psinw.htm
Weather apps daily data:
1 or <1ppb of sulfur dioxide in the air
Water - moderately hard to hard, with levels ranging from 110-130 ppm.

That is a wrong question.
A better question would be:
"Does snow contain enough sulfuric acid to be concerned about it?"
And the answer would be:
"No, it does not, unless you live near a chemical plant releasing sulfur oxides, or near a coal power plants without filtering of those oxides, or near active volcanos. But then, you could smell it in the air."

Typical rain water with background level pollution may contain $\pu{E-5 mol L-1}\ \ce{H2SO4}$.
Rather hard tap water may contain about $\pu{2 mmol L-1}$ of $\ce{Ca(HCO3)2}$.
As the reaction is in ratio 1 : 1
( $\ce{H2SO4 + Ca(HCO3) -> CaSO4 + 2 H2O + 2 CO2}$),
it gives the ratio rain water:tap water 200 : 1.
Imagine that your clothes are soaked by $\ce{1 L}$ of rain water or water from melted snow.
Then, for the neutralization of the trace sulfuric acid in clothes is needed $\pu{5 mL}$ of tap water. And much less of the washing detergent formula.
Additionally, the clothes would very like still contain traces of alkalic washing detergents for last washing, so neutralizing the traces of acid even on their own., by other words, the acid traces help to neutralize the alkalic residues in clothes.
The typical residual alkalinity after washing cotton fabric is reportedly $\pu{0.5-3 mmol kg-1}$ of dry fabric, what would be equivalent to acid of $\pu{25-150 L}$ of rain/snow water.

If a washer or dryer needs any cleaning, then due alkalic washing formulas, not due trace acidic substances.

Do you mean, in this case alkalic washing formulas (high ph, bleach) would be more harmful than trace acidic substances (sulfuric acid)? So I don’t need to worry about snow in the washer? (English is not my first language)

Melt the snow and taste it. Is it sour? No, it is not. Now, do not dare to taste washing formulas, otherwise your tongue will be slowly turning into a soap..

Right, I understand. I prefer minimal, gentle detergents… it’s why the info about snow’s natural acidity and then sulfuric acid contamination adding to it really made me so worry. So you think I don’t need to clean washer/dryer, and clothes will be unaffected?

No worries. pH buffering capacity of water, boosted by washing formulas, by many, many orders overcome acidity of melted snow.

Thank you. I just checked the measuring cup and apparently I wasn’t pouring enough of recommended dose. Will water still buffer the acidity of melted snow without a proper amount of washing formula? Or I contaminated the dryer now…

Well, do you have an idea what many orders mean?

Edited: I’m guessing the load was 6lbs or less, considered as “medium”. For medium, they instruct 44ml (line 3), and for heavily soiled or larger loads - 65ml (line 5). I did close to 44ml or a bit less. Would that be enough to buffer acidity?

PS. Detergent 8.5-8.9 pH, hard water.

Even the water, not speaking about the detergent, neutralise the acid without even noticing.

I just wanted to clarify, the 8.5-8.9 pH is for the detergent, not the water.

Tap water is rarely that alkalic. But it contains CO2/HCO3^- pH buffer and acid is neutralized by H3O+ + HCO3^- -> 2 H2O + CO2. Detergents contain much more neutralizing components, mostly Na2CO3. // It almost looks like you might have a phobia, but I hope it is just a lack of information. People are being soaked by rain water and melted snow for hundreds, even thousands of years and they are not walking around with clothes full of holes caused by an acid.
